# removing row header in datagrid view programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a Datagrid view, and I want to remove the row header for all rows...

I am trying to remove the rounded part as shown in the below figure (Row header)[image]

For that, I have written the code below.... but it's not working...

```
     private void dgvProducts_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
     {
         e.PaintCells(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);

         e.PaintHeader(DataGridViewPaintParts.All
             | DataGridViewPaintParts.Border
             | DataGridViewPaintParts.None
             | DataGridViewPaintParts.SelectionBackground
             | DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground);

         e.Handled = true;

     }
```

Would any pls give any sample code for removing the row header in Datagrid view .....

Many thanks. In advance.....

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Look for a RowHeadersVisible property on the DataGridView in the designer.

[image: RowHeadersVisible property set to false]

Answer (score 1):

From here:

[DataGridView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)

> **RowHeadersVisible** Gets or sets a value indicating whether the
>   column that contains row headers is displayed.

why are you being so mean at you to work with RowPrePaint when you can simply set this property to false?