# How to remove automatically generated empty column in a WinForms DataGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

So I am using a DataGrid in WinForms, and whenever I load into my application I get an empty blank column. Its causing all kinds of design problems, so I want to remove it. **How?**

It looks like this:
[image: Example image]

I am creating the columns programmatically when the form loads. Is the part of the problem? Its also not showing this on the designer page.

I am using *visual studio 2019* and *C# WinForms*.

Comment: I believe that's the row header.  The control should have a property to show or hide it.

Comment: Thank you @adv12. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324457/removing-row-header-in-datagrid-view-programmatically) and it has worked. What should I do with this question now? From my POV its not a duplicate as I did not know what row headers were and I know many other users wont. However, I don't believe its right for me to just post an answer to my question and it looks like I did it just for the reputation points.

Comment: Nothing wrong with self-answered questions.  I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using @adv12's comment, I was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324457/removing-row-header-in-datagrid-view-programmatically) thread. I found this column is called a "row header" using this I could disable it by going `Properties > RowHeadersVisible` and turning it into False (`this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible=false;`)

[image: Properties Changes]